# rendering problems with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, rendering

I'm having issues running this program on netbeans. It says,

```
Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Renderer
  location: class Box
```

I know the code runs because I saw my professor run it on cmd, but when I tried to run it on netbeans it wouldn't let me. Sorry if I sound noobish, but I just started learning java. He downloaded a rendering file and extracted it on the cmd line. I downloaded the file he used on the command line but I don't know how to import it into netbeans. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Box
{
public Box()
{
x = 25;
y = 25;
width = 20;
height = 30;
rotation = 0;
name = "NONE";
visible = true;
if (canvas == null) // For drawing
canvas = new Renderer();
}
public Box(int top, int left, int w, int h, int r, String n)
{
x = left;
y = top;
width = w;
height = h;
rotation = r;
name = n;
visible = true;
if (canvas == null) // For drawing
canvas = new Renderer();
}
public void draw()
{
canvas.add(x, y, width, height, rotation, name, visible); // For drawing
canvas.render(); // For drawing
}
private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private int rotation;
private String name;
private boolean visible;
private static Renderer canvas; // For drawing
}

public class useBox
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Box amanda = new Box();
amanda.draw();
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int width = 20;
int length = 30;
int degreesRotated = 0;
Box joe = new Box(x, y, width, length, degreesRotated, "Joe");
joe.draw();
Box meg = new Box(150, 150, 20, 30, 45, "Meg");
meg.draw();
}
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong -- you're trying to use classes, Renderer and Box, that Java can't find. NetBeans help will tell you how to get NetBeans to add these classes to your project's build path and then hopefully get your code running.

Comment: As an aside, your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.